# Riemann's fundamental methodology to derive the Riemann metric

Tags: differential-geometry

The sources I consulted on the advent of Riemannian Geometry (Wikipedia, general web searches) do not include how exactly Riemann found the correct components for the Riemann metric, in general and for specific surfaces. I can't find a version of his Habilitation lecture. I read that the Riemann curvature tensor and the metric are related, and I list some basic concepts he probably used below. Nonetheless a big gap remains as to how non-euclidean curves in the plane that lacked an image in R3 led him to the remarkable result that a new space with infinitesimal curvature can explain so many things.

1. Use the general equation
   $R_{abcd} = K (g_{ac} g_{db} - g_{ad} g_{cb})$
   and extend it to dimensions of 3 or more
2. Literally plug in equations of 2D non-euclidean curves into his general equations and increase dimensionality
3. Classify known differential equations by the scalar curvature of their described surfaces to get ideas of what a rotated hyperbola with constant negative curvature, for example, might produce.
4. Derive a mapping function from H2 to H3 (real hyperbolic space) by integrating a metric he already had. In other words, the equation for ds represented not just an infinitesimal arc length, but also a head to tail vector summation, representing a curved displacement, in its limit. These vector sums could be piecewise integrated to obtain the equation for an entire surface in H3.

I know he had many equations for the metric. The key question remains, for those based on the inner product of tangent vectors: how did he modify the directional derivative, because partial derivatives do not exist in the tangent space, to account for infinitesimal curvature, and obtain correct components for the metric from their inner product?

I read the post "Metric Tensor and Curvature" from 8 years ago and will watch the suggested video. A suggested source that contains details on Riemann's derivations is welcome.
I did not understand why one can't assign a flat metric to a 2-sphere. All distances are part of great circles, and circles have their arc length defined by the pythagorean equivalent in dx, dy, and dz. The surface has positive intrinsic curvature, but I don't understand why the requirement that the metric be assigned in a "smooth manner" means it can't be flat (pythagorean). However I am not very well-versed in topology.

Comment: Indeed, it's not that easy to show the sphere cannot have a flat metric.

Comment: If you're affiliated with an academic institution and can download Springer books, you can find Riemann's essay here: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-26042-6

Comment: Spivak talks about this in volume 2 of his books on differential geometry. He also includes a translation of Riemann’s lecture and a discussion of it. It’s well worth a look.

Comment: What is the name of the Spivak books? Hopefully the discussion has enough prose that it is comprehensible to me. A regular polygon becomes a circle as the number of sides gets large. But there aren't many 3D regular polygons that can approximate a sphere. As a shape in the elliptical curve group, being homeomorphic to 3d ovals, which may require a curved metric when expanded to 3 or more dimensions, it would make sense that a sphere has a curved metric.

Comment: A curved metric would mean the intrinsic derivative exists as a projection on to the tangent space.  A plane (flat) is tangent to a sphere at a point, so the projection would be zero. But tangent vectors are more like secants in the sense that they are a limiting value. Together they could represent a small volume. It is confusing.

Comment: Even considering a circle alone, it is hard to imagine a flat metric for one with infinitesimal radius. But no planar curve has a curved metric, only hypersurfaces do.